# ValueError: No closing quotation - slappasswd wrapper

Tags: python, getpass

I'm using `getpass` to edit LDAP passwords simply and efficiently. When I use a password, for example: `c;_pr8\\E0L)ec*\'E._rPBH?"4i9Tne` and try to run the program I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/editpasswd", line 73, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/local/bin/editpasswd", line 66, in main
    users_generated_password = generate_password()
  File "/usr/local/bin/editpasswd", line 52, in generate_password
    return send_command(PASSWORD_CREATION_COMMAND.format(users_password=password_to_generate))
  File "/usr/local/bin/editpasswd", line 33, in send_command
    command = shlex.split(command)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/shlex.py", line 279, in split
    return list(lex)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/shlex.py", line 269, in next
    token = self.get_token()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/shlex.py", line 96, in get_token
    raw = self.read_token()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/shlex.py", line 172, in read_token
    raise ValueError, "No closing quotation"
ValueError: No closing quotation
```

How I'm invoking the password:

```
PASSWORD_CREATION_COMMAND = "slappasswd -s {users_password}"

def send_command(command):
    command = shlex.split(command)
    sender = subprocess.Popen(
        command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT
    )
    res, err = sender.communicate()
    if res:
        return res.strip()
    if err:
        return err.strip()

def generate_password():
    password_to_generate = getpass.getpass(
        prompt="Enter the new password: "
    )
    confirm_password_to_generate = getpass.getpass(
        prompt="Confirm the password you just entered: "
    )
    if password_to_generate == confirm_password_to_generate:
        return send_command(PASSWORD_CREATION_COMMAND.format(users_password=password_to_generate))
    else:
        print("[!] password did not match")
        exit(-1)
```

What I think is causing this is when the command is run, the password has both `"` and `'` in it, so it fails because it's trying to find a closing quote, How can I got about creating this command to accept ANY password that is given to it, whether it has 1 or 7 quotes of each kind in it?

IE can I wrap it in triple quotes without effecting the password?

Comment: Why are you building a (broken) command line string, only to immediately unbuild it with `shlex.split`? Just build the argument list directly.

Comment: If you build the argument list directly, you get the following: `['slappasswd', '-s', 'c;_pr8\\\\E0L)ec*\\\'E._rPBH?"4i9Tne']` which is all escaped. Will the escaped sequences work successfully?

Comment: @user2357112 just tried it and it works.

Answer (score -1):

Figured it out with help from the comments. Issue was that (as mentioned) the strings closing quotes was not there. So if you build the argument string directly instead of using shlex to split it, it will automatically escape the quotes/slashes. For example:

```
def build_list(string):
    return string.split(" ")

# build_list("""slappasswd -s c;_pr8\\E0L)ec*\'E._rPBH?"4i9Tne""")
#<= ['slappasswd', '-s', 'c;_pr8\\\\E0L)ec*\\\'E._rPBH?"4i9Tne']
```

Once everything is correctly escaped you can go ahead and run it and it'll work just fine.

Comment: You're still going through a (broken) command line string. Using `str.split` will give you problems with whitespace in a password. Do you know how to write a list literal?

Comment: @user2357112 how many end users do you know of that use whitespace in a password?

Comment: I don't know other people's passwords in general, but trying a few weak passwords with spaces in them on [HaveIBeenPwned's pwned passwords tool](https://haveibeenpwned.com/Passwords) shows that plenty of passwords with spaces in them have turned up in password breaches. It's simple enough to build a list directly with `['slappasswd', '-s', password]`, so why create problems for yourself?